# Shell script program to Extract part of time stamp in message.log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have data like below in v`ar/log/messages.log` now I need to search WAM data line and Exrtract only part of time stamp

For Example

```
2013-07-09T02:22:28.535639Z [24] user.info WebAppMgr WAM APPLAUNCH_INITIATED
```

Above line contains `WAM`, I need only `22:28.535639Z` data in messages.log

```
2013-07-09T02:22:28.535639Z [24] user.info WebAppMgr WAM APPLAUNCH_INITIATED 
2013-07-09T02:22:21.817372Z [17] user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.calculator
2013-07-09T02:22:21.818442Z [17] user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.settings
2013-07-09T02:24:04.738067Z [120] user.info WebAppMgr WAM APPLAUNCH_INITIATED 
2013-07-09T02:22:21.846636Z [17] user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.notes
2013-07-09T02:22:21.851727Z [17] user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.firstuse
2013-07-09T02:22:21.854172Z [17] user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.isis2
2013-07-09T02:22:21.863786Z [17] user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.sysapp.voicedial
2013-07-09T02:24:04.746751Z [120] user.info WebAppMgr WAM APP CREATED WINDOW
```

I am able to extract `2013-07-09T02:22:28.535639Z`. I need to know how to extract `22:28.535639Z`

```
#! /bin/sh
awk '/\ WAM/ {print $1"\t"}' /home/santosh/messages
```

I get output like

```
2013-07-09T02:22:28.535639Z
2013-07-09T02:24:04.738067Z
2013-07-09T02:24:04.746751Z
```

But I Need Only below data

```
22:28.535639Z
24:04.738067Z
24:04.746751Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in your current awk call:

```
awk '/\<WAM\>/ {split($1, a, ":"); print a[2] ":" a[3]}' file
```

The `\<` and `\>` are word boundary assertions.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('path/to/logfile') as logfile:
    for line in logfile:
        if "WAM" in line:
            timestamp = line.partition(" ")[0].partition(":")[2]
            print timestamp
```

Running the above code on your example, I get this as output:

```
22:28.535639Z
24:04.738067Z
24:04.746751Z
```

Comment: with open ('var/log/messages') as logfile: but throwing error like
msg2.py: 1: msg2.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: I wrote my code in python 2.7. Please make sure you're using the same version

Answer (score 1):

Use [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> strs = "2013-07-09T02:22:28.535639Z"
>>> d = datetime.strptime(strs,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
>>> d.strftime('%M:%S.%fZ')
'24:04.746751Z'
```

**Code:**

```
with open('/home/santosh/messages') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'WAM' in line:
            d = datetime.strptime(line.split()[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
            print d.strftime('%M:%S.%fZ')
...             
22:28.535639Z
24:04.738067Z
24:04.746751Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the tags you used and the examples you gave, it seems you're open to shell solutions in addition to Python-based ones. Since variety is the spice of life, use `sed`:

```
$ sed -n  '/WAM/{s/.*T[0-9]*:\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\.[0-9]*Z\).*/\1/g;p}' /home/santosh/messages 
22:28.535639Z
24:04.738067Z
24:04.746751Z
```

For any line that contains "WAM", find the text matching the pattern "[anything]Tdigits:(digits:digits.digitsZ)[anything]", then replace the line with just the part of the matching text that's in parentheses ("digits:digits.digtsZ") and then print it. The `-n` switch to `sed` just means do not print anything unless you tell it to (i.e. with the `p` command).

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex`:

**Python:**

```
import re
with open('/home/santosh/messages') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(r'^.*?:(\S+).*?WAM',line)
        if m: print m.group(1)
```

**Perl:**

```
while ($line = <STDIN>){
    if ($line =~ m/^.*?:(\S+).*?WAM/){
        print "$1\n";
        }
}
```

**output:**

```
$ perl so.pl < abc
22:28.535639Z
24:04.738067Z
24:04.746751Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `awk`:

```
awk -F':| ' '/\<WAM\>/{print $2":"$3}' /home/santosh/messages
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat test.txt | cut -d " " -f 1 | cut -d "T" -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 2-3
```

Added your data in the file... I "cut" command can do the trick...

Comment: Brrr... Four external utilities used and `cat` is absolutely useless!

Answer (score 1):

A pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution:

```
while read a x x x b x; do
  [ "$b" == WAM ] && echo ${a#*:}
done </var/log/messages.log
```

Output:

```
22:28.535639Z
24:04.738067Z
24:04.746751Z
```